# Razor Import Caching problem

Tags: razor, tbb, caching

Right now it seems that the razor imports get cached, and you need to "touch" (make a minor change) to the TBB that is using the razor import.

This usually isnt a problem unless of course you're using the import on a handful of other TBBs, requiring you to go "touch" all of them.

Is there a way to use the latest version of the imports automatically get the latest version of the razor and not require the "touch".

The closest thing I could find about this was on this question.  [Embedded Razor Templates](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15366/embedded-razor-templates/15380#15380)

Answer (score 2):

What I didn't explain in the answer to [Embedded Razor Templates](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15366/embedded-razor-templates/15380#15380) was the reason why. What's happening is that the templates get compiled dynamically, and the resulting type is loaded in the appDomain. If you create a new version of a template building block, the includes are resolved as a simple text include and become part of the resulting type. The mediator tracks the relation with the TBB, but not the imports. If I remember correctly, this tracking logic was more sophisticated in previous versions, but this was a casualty of having to fix a memory leak.

It's known that the current architecture has its weaknesses, and that the next version of the mediator ought probably to be a re-write with some architectural improvements, such as programmatic management of application domains so that the types representing earlier TBB versions can be unloaded.

Alex Klock mentions [here](https://github.com/alex-klock/razor-mediator-4-tridion) that the main focus is now on version 2.0, but that there may possibly be a version 1.4. So if you really want a solution, one option is to get in touch with Alex and volunteer to help. If you can solve the problem on the current architecture, then a pull request would probably work.